# clang/llvm: equivalent to GNU ld's --defsym=<address> or --just-symbols?

Tags: c, llvm, clang, ld

We're using the

```
--just-symbols=<file>
```

option in GNU ld to take a bunch of absolute symbols and link against them. We might be interested in using clang/llvm instead, but we currently rely on this feature of ld.

Is there an equivalent for the llvm linker ? Or at least something akin to

```
--defsym=<absolute address>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using clang/llvm with the GNU linker?